# Unable to close a modal window with javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window for deletion confirmation.  Somehow I can't close this modal window.  The following is how I coded.  Does anyone have a clue what I did wrong?

```js
$('#delpkgdtlPrompt').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  $('#AddPkgItm').modal('hide');
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var pkgid = button.data('pkgid');
  var pkgdtldesc = button.data('pkgdtldesc');

  var dataString = 'pkgid=' + pkgid;
  alert(dataString);
  var modal = $(this);
})

$(document).on("click", ".btncancel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('#delpkgdtlPrompt').modal('hide');
  $('#AddPkgItm').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="delpkgdtlPrompt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delpkgdtlPromptLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="delpkgdtlPromptLabel">Delete confirmation</h2>
      </div>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="frmdelpkgdtl">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="pkgdtldesc" name="pkgdtldesc">
            <p>You are about to delete the record</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button name="btncancel" id="btncancel" type="submit" class="btncancel btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
            <button name="btndelpkgdtl" id="btndelpkgdtl" type="submit" class="clsdelpkgdtl btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure the cancel button's click event has been fired as the other modal window (AddPkgItm) is shown after the button is clicked.  Just the confirmation does not go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#delpkgdtlPrompt').modal('hide');
```

should do it. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHJBlhZgFhHLmO7y5dwz?p=preview)

Comment: since the button with class "btncancel" is inside the modal dialogue, you should add the attribute  data-dismiss="delpkgdtlPrompt" to it so that it closes when it is clicked.

Comment: I coded (see my second javascript) as you posted but it doesn't go away.  The line of code did get executed and the modal appears underneath of it.

Comment: Thanks Abdul Mannan.  Tried as suggested but no luck.

Comment: @JimW use the "shown.bs.modal" event instead of 'show.bs.modal'.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to use shown.bs.modal.  Can you post a sample?

Comment: @JimW i have updated my answer. See the plunker link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106963/discussion-between-jim-w-and-abdul-mannan).